# data is not inserting into table, this DAL function call multiple time if we select multiple material & quantity

Tags: c#, oracle

in this, error coming in catch 'ORA-01084: invalid argument in OCI call' 
isearch that why this error came normally in code, it showing below solution:

The issue lies deep in Oracle .Net drivers. We had Qty field defined as an INT. Due to internal architecture Qty could be negative or null. 95% of cases Qty was positive integer (as it should be), but sometimes due to adjustments and other factors it could be null or negative.

So in the end I traced it to the order of how you put your records into the database:

```
Qty 1 Qty 0 Qty null Qty -1
```

works correctly. But in this case:

```
Qty null Qty 1 Qty -1
```

will blow with OCI invalid argument on "-1" value.

I created a ticket on Oracle, and send it down to our product team to fix. Since then I moved on, so not too sure if and when was it fixed.

But in this 0 or NULL value is not coming.

Note : inserting data in query, that will correctly inserted but using stored procedure is not working.

Comment: which parameter is it that might be null here? does an exception happen? note: ado.net parameters with `null` value *are not sent* - it needs to be `DbNull.Value` instead

Comment: Ya its working now @Marc Gravell Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (DBNull.Value.Equals(objComplainDetails.YARD_NAME) | objComplainDetails.YARD_NAME == string.Empty) arrParam[0].Value = null; else arrParam[0].Value = objComplainDetails.YARD_NAME;
```

like this, all data should be code in DAL.

Answer (score 0):

ADO.NET has a "feature" that often trips people over; parameters with a `null` value **are not sent**; you need to check for `null` and specify the value `DBNull.Value` instead. One way to do with is with null-coalescing:

```
someParam.Value = (object)intendedValue ?? DBNull.Value;
```

Note that most ORM tools (EF, etc) and ADO.NET helper utilities (Dapper, etc) will do this *for you*.